# Login to google using oauth2 javascript api in cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, oauth-2.0, google-fit

How to access Mi Band data using Google Fit api? I want to write an application where user can login with Google account and can see all his fitness data from Mi Band. Since Mi Fit application can sync data to Google Fit api, I want to use google rest api using Javascript. I am making apache cordova app and i am using the following line in config.xml

```
allow-navigation href="*"
```

This is opening google login popup in the same webview in android. But once the authentication is done, i am getting the message please close this popup. And when I close and open the app, the api calls are happening. I want to know how to close this window automatically.

Edit:
I recently found out that webview can share resources with browser. So is there a way to open authentication popup in browser and share cookies with `WebView` to make the login.